# how to make super class property as "readonly"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created one class "MyView" which is inherited from UItableViewCell. Now MyView has setter and getter for frame of UItableViewCell. But I want to make it as readonly. So that from other classes,I should not be able to set frame of MyView. I tried by overriding frame property and by making it readonly. But still it can be set. Am I missing anything?

```
   @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGRect frame;
```

Thanks

Comment: You realize there is already a property called `frame` on `UIView` right?  You shouldn't name it that, it will cause weird behavior.  Name it something else and try again.

Comment: @borrrden I think that's the idea, overriding the behaviour of the existing frame property to make it readonly.

Comment: Oh, my misunderstanding then.

Comment: Ya James, My thinking was like same. By overriding existing property will make him readonly. But it is not working..

Comment: @iSwap Have you tried overriding the setter to just ignore the new value? There might be a better way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this kind of behavior is allowed.  What you *can* do though, is override the setter method of the property to be a no-op.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSLog(@"Do Nothing");
}
```

Comment: Ya this will work, but i guess it will not be right way. Since while writing it will not give warning and will tell that you are not allowed.

Comment: You can't remove methods from a class that you didn't write (UIView).  That would cause all kinds of chaos.